# Opening a page from Email link does not populate the form with data, in that page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, asp.net, .net, query-string

On performing some action(approve/reject a request) an email is generated with a link in it.
On clicking the link, a SharePoint QA page opens that contains a form.
All that works well!

My issue is, that form is not populated with data that were entered during form submission.

How do I populate that form with data?

I am also using QueryString and the following is the URL:

`https ://abc.xyz.com/sites/def/Pages/tests.aspx?uID=56` (just to show the QueryString)

The entire thing works well when I move from one page to another!
Data is not being populated only when I open my page from the EMAIL, I just get a blank form.

I am sorry that I cannot post the code here since it is too huge and there are series of methods that use each other.

Hoping I get some help.. Thank you :)

Comment: Where is your code written in PageLoad method or on other life cycle event? Also, are you check `Page.IsPostBack`?